# Cannot add reference to Word in Visual Studio 2008, in Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ms-word, ms-office

For some reason I can not add reference to MS Word file MSWORD.OLB. It should be (and file is) located in:

```
c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE11\
```

I guess that problem is in Windows 7, since with XP I did not had same problem. Of course, Office is installed on machine.

Also, I noticed that Path in Reference properties is empty... Can I fill it somehow manually, to avoid this problem, or there is some other solution?

Comment: Windows 7 can find it.. question is what machine are you trying to add the reference or where it's saying it can't find it..? you can't assume that if you create it locally on your machine that the target site will share the same installed version or path.. you would have to Reference it from the GAC of the target machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One should install the primary office interops and reference those, not the actual programs.:

[Microsoft Office 2010: Primary Interop Assemblies Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3508)

[2007 Microsoft Office System Update: Redistributable Primary Interop Assemblies](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=18346)